# Run-time error '91'

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded a macro with subtotals and when i run it this is the error i am getting.  The error is associated with the first line

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Celine HB").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Celine HB").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
        Range("E1:E301"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Celine HB").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

Comment: Is there no other information with that error?

Comment: I don't know why this question was marked as a duplicate, since the issue here is *not* because OP needs `Set` - it's an `AutoFilter` associated error.

Comment: Yes the error says Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

Answer (score 1):

You will get that error when there is no `AutoFilter` set on the sheet.  To handle that wrap you code if a test for presence of the filter, this this

```
If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Celine HB").AutoFilterMode Then
    ' your code
Else
    'No Filter set, what now?
End if
```